# Can a knotted sphere isometrically embed into $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, knot-theory, embeddings, isometries

All smooth simple closed curves in $\mathbb R^3$ (knotted or not) can be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb R^2$ as a circle of equal arclength.

The situation for knotted spheres seems more complicated because metric surfaces are more rigid. Here I am unsure that if given a smooth knotted sphere in $\mathbb R^4$ if there is a way to embed into $\mathbb R^3$ while preserving its metric structure. So my question is:

> Does there exist a nontrivial smooth knotted sphere in $\mathbb R^4$ which can
> be smoothly isometrically embedded into $\mathbb R^3$? And if so,
> are there any concrete examples?

In all of the above, the Riemannian metric structures are assumed to be inherited from the ambient space.

Comment: How can a knot be embedded into the plane??

Comment: There's a slight inconsistency in terminology, but I believe the author at that point in the question is thinking of "circle" as being a synonym for "knot".

Comment: Can you clarify the metrics you're using in the isometries, what exactly you mean by a round circle, and be specific about what the analogous situation is when you move up in dimension?

Comment: So here I am thinking of a knot K in R^3 as a simple smooth closed curve and the isometry to a circle (of equal perimeter) does not arise from an ambient isotopy (unless K is the unknot). Assuming K is of unit length, the isometry can be seen by considering an ant walking along the knot at unit speed from a starting point p. A point the ant reaches at time t gets maped to (cos 2 pi t, sin 2 pi t). For x, y on K the distance along K is the same as the associated distance along the unit circle in R^2.

Comment: I've made some edits that hopefully help. I removed the adjective "round" since it doesn't really affect my main question (but i just meant a circle as in elementary school as opposed to a topological circle). As for the Riemannian metric structures, they should all be assumed to be induced by the ambient space. And to elaborate on the situation in higher dimension: is there a smooth Riemannian submanifold of R^4 which is a nontrivially knotted topological sphere and can be smoothly isometrically embedded into R^3?

Comment: It can be done $C^1$.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning it can be done C^1 (via the Nash-Kuiper theorem I presume). However, I am mainly interested in maps with more regularity. Smooth would be ideal, but C^2 would be interesting too.

Comment: Maybe you are aware of this, but this paper gives an example of a metric on $S^2$ which does not admit a $C^2$ isometric embedding into $\mathbb R^3$: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214429999.

Answer (score 8):

A spun knot will give a 2-sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$ whose intrinsic metric embeds into $\mathbb{R}^3$ isometrically as a surface of revolution.

Take a tangle $T$ in $\mathbb{R}^3_+$ with two ends on $\mathbb{R}^2$, that is an embedding $e: ([0,1],\{ 0, 1\}) \to (\mathbb{R}^3_+,\mathbb{R}^2)$. We may assume that $e$ is an isometry. Spin $T$ about $\mathbb{R}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ to get a surface $S$.

[image: spun knot]
If $T$ is knotted then $S$ will be knotted. Then there exists an isometric embedding $e’:([0,1],\{0,1\})\to (\mathbb{R}^2_+,\mathbb{R})$ so that $d(e’(t),\mathbb{R})=d(e(t),\mathbb{R}^2)$ for all $t,\in [0,1]$ and thus the surface of revolution $S’$ of $e’([0,1])$ about $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is isometric to $S$.

[image]